# Insert into two tables in one request

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have two tables: `Human` and `Student`. Student extends from Human.

I tried to do it like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HUMAN_Type AS OBJECT(CIN NUMBER(8), NameCHAR(32),SurNAME CHAR(32),Email VARCHAR(32),Adress varchar(32)) NOT FINAL;
CREATE TYPE Student_Type UNDER HUMAN_Type (NumSTUD NUMBER(3),Dat_EXP Date, Nbr Number(2));
CREATE table Human of HUMAN_Type (primary key (CIN));
CREATE table Student of Student_Type (primary key (NumStud));
```

If I want to insert a Student, should I make two request (one for Student and one for Human) or is there a way to insert into Human and Student in one single request?

Comment: See [multi-table INSERT in the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2121682). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also should specify that CIN is foreign key in Student table to relate Student-Human relationship.